# How can I get rid of the margin under the footer in vuejs

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I'm making a footer using vuejs and buefy.

I have defined App.vue as below, but there is a white margin under the footer.

```
// App.vue

<template>
  <div id="app">
    <main-header />
      <router-view/>
    <main-footer />
  </div>
</template>

...
<style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>
```

I'm not sure what these margins are.

How can I do it?

++++
The code for the footer I wrote is below.

```
// Main Footer

<template>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="content has-text-centered">
      <p>
        <strong>Web</strong>
        <br>
        © 2020  •
      </p>
    </div>
  </footer>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "MainFooter",
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  footer {
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Hey there, can you show us some screenshot like what problem you are facing, like exactly how the footer is placed. That would be helpful

Comment: @tbhaxor OK, I added the image

Comment: It most probably isn't a margin, rather your page height is not set to take up the viewport height. Look into how you can do that

Comment: Use DevTools to inspect the margins. Some of that margin is probably from the user agent styles for `<p>`.

Answer (score 1):

You set the margin to 0 for the `body` but not the `footer`.
To set it for the footer, you can do something similar to

```
footer {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I still have spaces under the footer.

Comment: can you show the `<main-footer />` component code looks like?

Comment: are you sure the footer is the one with the margin, and not the inner div/p tags? To test this, you can do `html, footer {margin: 0}` as well

Comment: I am still the same.

Comment: I have attached an image of my Footer.